# FishPig Attribute Splash Pages Extension Bugs

Tags: model, collection

I'm evaluating the FishPig Attribute Splash Pages extension for a client, and I've run into a few bugs.  I've got support requests into the extension vendor, but since it's a free extension I figured I'd throw them out to the community as well in case any of you have fixes/workaround/insights.  This is for the recently released `2.2.0` version of the extension.

Bonus question: The [reviews](http://fishpig.co.uk/attribute-splash-pages.html) mention a FishPig GitHub account — does anyone know the account name on this?  The [obvious candidate](https://github.com/fishpig) doesn't have any repositories.

### Pagination

Pagination appears to be broken

[image]

The above image is a 2 item list, with the "per page" set to 1.  The pager HTML is correct, but the entire list is output on each page.  This appears to be caused by an early call to `count` on the collection.

Does anyone have a fix/workaround.insight on this?

### Group Page Display Mode

On the Groups editing form, there's a Drop Down labeled Display Mode that allows you to select

- Products Only
- Static Block Only
- Static Block and Product

However, this field doesn't save.  The values in HTML for this field are strings (`PRODUCT`, `PRODUCT_AND_BLOCK`, etc), but the database column in a `tinyint`.  Also, the group page template and view block doesn't appear to reference this column for anything.

Does this column drive any behavior?  Is it something left over from a previous version?

Comment: There is an entry in the latest release changelog: `05/03/2013 - v2.2.0.2 - Fixed issue that broke pager on group pages` possibly fixed in latest release? A github account would be nice for all free magento connect modules ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this one out, as the issues mentioned above have been taken care of in the latest extension release.

Comment: Were you able to fix the pagination issue as well? As currently when I select "All" or "22" from show dropdown, it takes me to home page of the site with the parameter attached to it e.g. mysite.com/?limit=all. Other than that, wishlist and add to bag is also not working for me :(